# Loading Sounds Into an Array to Be Played At Random

Tags: android, andengine

I am trying to load up 9 sounds files into an array so that they can be played at a certain value (1 to 9) when my sprite performs an animation.

So far, I have created the sounds using the AndEngine SoundFactory.

```
this.mGrondin1 = SoundFactory.createSoundFromAsset(this.mEngine.getSoundManager(), getApplicationContext(), "Earn my pay.wav");
this.mGrondin2 = SoundFactory.createSoundFromAsset(this.mEngine.getSoundManager(), getApplicationContext(), "Spaghetti code.wav");
this.mGrondin3 = SoundFactory.createSoundFromAsset(this.mEngine.getSoundManager(), getApplicationContext(), "Business major.wav");
this.mGrondin4 = SoundFactory.createSoundFromAsset(this.mEngine.getSoundManager(), getApplicationContext(), "Microsoft code.wav");
this.mGrondin5 = SoundFactory.createSoundFromAsset(this.mEngine.getSoundManager(), getApplicationContext(), "How I would do it.wav");
this.mGrondin6 = SoundFactory.createSoundFromAsset(this.mEngine.getSoundManager(), getApplicationContext(), "Not efficient.wav");
this.mGrondin7 = SoundFactory.createSoundFromAsset(this.mEngine.getSoundManager(), getApplicationContext(), "Flying Blind.wav");
this.mGrondin8 = SoundFactory.createSoundFromAsset(this.mEngine.getSoundManager(), getApplicationContext(), "Minus two.wav");
this.mGrondin9 = SoundFactory.createSoundFromAsset(this.mEngine.getSoundManager(), getApplicationContext(), "Turn off your life.wav");
```

and now I would like to load them all up into an easily accessible form like an array. How can I do this?

**UPDATE**
Instead of creating a whole bunch of sounds and trying to load them into an array, I simply crated an array of sounds and loaded all the files into it.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < arSounds.length; i++) {
            this.arSounds[i] = SoundFactory.createSoundFromAsset(
                    this.mEngine.getSoundManager(),
                    getApplicationContext(), "Grondin" + (i + 1) + ".wav");
        }
```

this loaded them all into arSounds array. Then for the random playing I did

```
    Random gen;
    arSounds[gen.nextInt(8)].play();
```

Comment: When you 'load' them into your array, will you need `mGrondin1`, `mGrondin2` (and the others) anywhere else in your code? If not, then just create a `Sound` array. Example `Sound[] mySoundArray = new Sound[9];` and add each one to it one at a time.